# Is it possible to use POS(Proof of stake) blockchain instead of aws to host our files and data?

Tags: blockchain

Is it possible to use POS(Proof of stake) blockchain instead of aws to host our files and data?

And how can we do a financial analysis between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the best methods for hosting data in a decentralized manner are:

Storj, Siacoin, and IPFS

A blockchain is really overkill for storing files: you don't need to record that nothing happened every ten minutes just so that you can store an occasional file.

And there are projects trying to do the cloud computing model of AWS: Golem (for one time computations), Iagon (for big data on big storage), and Noia (for fast content delivery).

A combination of Iagon, Noia, and IPFS would be the best model to create  a full suite like AWS.

Comment: I want to know if POS blockchain can replace Cloud computing model of AWS?

Comment: awesome, Thanks a ton!